# Anime where a boy says “By the breath of the mega (something)”

Tags: story-identification, anime

In a fantasy world with magic, a boy has an amulet that gives him power when he says “By the breath of the mega (something)”, but he says it wrong and gets corrected by an old man. He is friends with a troll.

There is an antagonist who has a big sort of castle on the head of a giant flying manta ray looking beast.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should check out the suggestions for [story-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) and [anime-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407) questions to see if they help you remember anything else you can [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 3):

*Lanfeust Quest* (2013).

Basically in the world of Troy, most people have a unique magic power. Lanfeust's (the main character) is to melt metal. At some point he, his troll friend, the town's elder and his two daughters go on an adventure to face the evil Thanos <sub><sup>no, not that one</sup></sub>.

[image: Lanfeust Quest characters]

Thanos rides a dragon ship which sort of looks like a manta ray:

[image: Thanos' dragon ship]

The clip below (in French) has Lanfeust trying to stop the dragon ship with some kind of amulet and "by the breath of the **Mago**hamoth, shield power":

Comment: If this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for [*Lanfeust Quest*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanfeust_Quest)

- *"In a fantasy world with magic, a boy has a amulet that gives him power when he says “By the breath of the mega(something)”"*

the serie, based off [a French comics series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanfeust_of_Troy#Synopsis) is set

> On the world of Troy, most humans have a single magic power. Each power is unique to the person and includes such diverse feats as walking on water, personal teleportation, and causing thirst in others.

the main character of the cartoon (have not seen the comics) Lanfeust as an amulet that grants him multiple powers by using the phrase *"By the breath of the Magohamoth"*, which you can see in [this vimeo video](https://vimeo.com/63309993) (at around 1 minute 10 seconds)

- *"There is an antagonist who has a big sort of castle on the head of a giant flying manta ray looking beast."*

that would be Thanos

[image: Thanos] [image: Thanos and Lanfeust]

and his Ship is on what i would describe it more of a Dragon

[image: Thanos's SHip]

you can also see it in the vimeo link i posted